Can Nginx Ingress implement a client credentials grant workflow with Oauth2-proxy and Keycloak?
I'm trying to implement below Client Credentials Grant workflow in k8s with Nginx Inress, Keycloak, and OAuth2-proxy:
ClientApp (sends client_ID/secret) -> to KeyCloak and receives access_token
ClientApp (sends application-request) -> to Nginx Ingress To access the API behind
Nginx Ingress (maybe with help of OAuth2 Proxy) Verifies the access_token
Nginx redirects the ClientApp application-request to the backend API
below is my OAuth2-proxy configuration:
    # Provider config
    provider="keycloak"
    provider_display_name="Keycloak"
    login_url="http://KeycloakFQDN.com:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth"
    redeem_url="http://KeycloakFQDN.com:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token"
    #validate_url="http://<KeycloakAddress>/realms/<KeycloakRealmName>/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo"
    #profile_url="http://<KeycloakAddress>/realms/<KeycloakRealmName>/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo"
    ssl_insecure_skip_verify=true
    # Client config
    client_id="app1-client"
    client_secret="HBnmPDynksWlRfw96lAlBYtihfysbctw"
    cookie_secret="Zzol000Ug0hQlFhIcklHj9VHsrQRUw_ME1oMTZZTy0="
    cookie_secure="false"
    # Upstream config
    http_address="0.0.0.0:4180"
    upstreams="file:///dev/null"
    oidc_issuer_url="http://KeycloakFQDN:8080/realms/master"
    cookie_domains=["AppFQDN.com"]
    scope="openid"
    whitelist_domains=[".AppFQDN.com:*"]

below is oauth2-proxy ingress definition:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: oauth2-proxy
  namespace: oauth2-proxy
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: myapp.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: oauth-proxy
            port:
              number: 4180
        path: /oauth2
        pathType: Prefix

I'm able to get an access token with Curl against Keycloak URL directly,
but what annotations shall I add to the backend API Ingress definition to allow the rest of the workflow (Nginx to verify clientApp AccessToken and allowing it to access the backend API?
